# Add encryption on uploading object in S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-requests

```
import requests

url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<some-bucket-name>'

data = { 'key': 'test/test.jpeg' }
files = { 'file': open('test.jpeg', 'rb') }

r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

I want to upload an image to the S3 bucket as above.The S3 bucket is enabled with AES256 encryption. How will I be able to specify the encryption in post requests?

Comment: Does this work without `ServerSideEncryption`?

Comment: @Marcin If the S3 bucket is not enabled with encription,it will work.My question is to understand the way to mension the ServerSideEncryption,if S3 is enables with AES256 encription

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Warning

It seems like you have configured your bucket in a way that allows unauthenticated `PUT` requests into it - this is dangerous and may become expensive, because essentially anybody that knows your bucket name can put data into it and **you'll have to pay the bill**. I recommend you change that.

---

If you want it to stay that way, you can use headers to configure the encryption type for each object as described in the `PutObject` [API-Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html).

The *most relevant* (excluding SSE-C encryption) are these two:

> **x-amz-server-side-encryption**
>
> The server-side encryption algorithm used when storing this object in Amazon S3 (for example, AES256, aws:kms).
>
> Valid Values: `AES256 | aws:kms`
>
> **x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id**
>
> If `x-amz-server-side-encryption` is present and has the value of `aws:kms`,
> this header specifies the ID of the AWS Key Management Service (AWS
> KMS) symmetrical customer managed customer master key (CMK) that was
> used for the object.
>
> If the value of x-amz-server-side-encryption is aws:kms, this header
> specifies the ID of the symmetric customer managed AWS KMS CMK that
> will be used for the object. If you specify
> `x-amz-server-side-encryption:aws:kms`, but do not provide
> `x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id`, Amazon S3 uses the AWS
> managed CMK in AWS to protect the data.

You can add these in your `requests.post` call.

The [API-Docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) of the requests library specify how to do that, so it should look roughly like this:

```py
requests.post(
    url,
    data=data,
    files=files,
    headers={"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES:256"}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  My question is, how will i mention the encryption as AES256 on the requests. post? What syntax should I follow?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation I quoted, the `x-amz-server-side-encryption` with the value `AES256` is going to do the trick :)

Comment: I already went though it before posting the question .But i couldn't figure-out the way to mention the tag.Do you think it will  be like below?`                                                                                             `r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files, x-amz-server-side-encryption='AES256' )`

Comment: I added a sample